# Add A Service to Custom Route Decorator nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a Custom Route Decorator which is suppose to use a method from a Service but the service returns undefined. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'findCustomer' of undefined`;
Fairly new to nestjs

```
//Custom Route Decorator - CustomerDecorator

export async function getCustomerFromExeContext(
  context: ExecutionContext,
): Promise<Customer> {
  let organizationService: OrganizationService;
  const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();

  if (!req.params.orgId)
    throw new HttpException('OrgId not found', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

  const customer = await organizationService.findCustomer(
    parseInt(req.params.orgId),
  );
  if (!customer) {
    throw new HttpException('Customer not found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  return customer;
}

export const GetCustomer = createParamDecorator(
  (_, context: ExecutionContext) => getCustomerFromExeContext(context),
);
```

This is the Route within the controller that utilize the Decorator

```
//Controller

@Get(':orgId')
  get(@GetCustomer() customer: Customer) {
    return this.organizationService.get(customer.customerId);
  }
```

Is there a way I can call and use the service within the decorator function without returning `undefined`?

Comment: What does your controller constructor look like? Did you specify that it depends on the organization service? Looks like NestJS hasn't injected it.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in a decorator. Use a custom pipe

Comment: @catgirlkelly I have it in the constructor as
`private readonly organizationService: OrganizationService`

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I'm fairly new to nestjs. Can I use the pipe to call the service in the route decorator?

Comment: A pipe is its own class, but can transform a value in the route handler, before it makes it to the route handler. This could be changing `req.body` from a JSON to a DTO instance, hydrating an id to a full object, or anything like that. [Here's the docs on pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes). You can use DI in them. Decorators, in general, should just instruct Nest how to use the `ExecutionContext` to pass a value to the route handler

Comment: okay, so that means, I can create Custom Pipe which will get the `customer` based on the params and simply pass it in the route handler just like the Decorator. 
I am sure pipes can be used to check if an item exist, right? @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0):

The error tells clearly what exactly happening

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'findCustomer' of undefined

The error means `organizationService` is undefined and you are calling `findCustomer` on undefined.

Here

`let organizationService: OrganizationService;`

you create an undefined variable. you need to initialize it first.

If you have any dependency inside `OrganizationService` then you need to inject that class object. if not just `new OrganizationService()` will work